# Config Symfony2 and Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am new to Symfony2 and Doctrine as well actually anyway. I am trying to config my Doctrine so i can use it in my Symfony2 project.

I have created a DatabaseRepository file where I am doing my connection. When i execute this file i get an error:

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to DatabaseRepository::__construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\DBAL\Connection, none given, called in app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 2363
```

My DatabaseRepository file:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Doctrine;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Connection;
use Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class DatabaseRepository
{
    /**
     * @var Connection
     */
    protected $db;

    /**
     * @var LoggerInterface
     */
    protected $logger;

    /**
     * @param Connection $connection
     * @param LoggerInterface $logger
     */
    public function __construct(
        Connection $connection,
        LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->db = $connection;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }
}
```

doctrine sits under Vendor directory. I am using `use` to add the connection but this still will not work.

OK guys sorry I think this question is incomplete I will all these.

This is where I call my DatabaseRepository:

```
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Repository;

use Acme\DemoBundle\Doctrine\DatabaseRepository;

class TestRepo {

    public $doctrine;

    public function __construct(
        DatabaseRepository $databaseRepository
    ){
        $this->doctrine = $databaseRepository;
    }


    public function test()
    {

    }

}
```

And the Below are the services:

```
<!-- Doctrine -->
<service id="database_repository"
         class="Acme\DemoBundle\Doctrine\DatabaseRepository">
        <argument type="service" id="Doctrine\DBAL\Connection" />
        <argument type="service" id="Psr\Log\LoggerInterface" />
</service>

<service id="test_repo"
         class="Acme\DemoBundle\Repository\TestRepo">
    <argument type="service" id="database_repository" />
</service>
```

As soogested in comments below I added arguments used to my database_repository service.

But now I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException' with message 'The service "jdatabase_repository" has a dependency on a non-existent service "doctrine\dbal\connection"
```

Comment: How do you create this object? This exception is a matter of invocation, not the declaration.

Comment: do I have to create a service for it..?

Comment: You shouldn't use the connection like that. Doctrine (and his config) should handle all that... Look at http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/book/doctrine.html#configuring-the-database

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's a service or not. It's just it looks like you don't provide required arguments to constructor while creating the object. `use` statement doesn't relieve you from passing instances of Doctrine to the constructor. It just means that you will use classes from that namespace in this file.

Comment: Yes I did config my parameter.yml with correct DB details just did not want to descales these. But the issue here is the Doctrine\DBAL\Connection; just not to sure whats wrong exacly

Comment: The issue is that you don't provide required params to constructor. Once again - how do you create/access the object of the `DatabaseRepository` class.

Comment: Please Check the edits guys

Comment: Yeah that's clear now. Take a look at your `database_repository` service configuration. You don't provide any `<argument> sections which means you don't provide arguments for constructor.

Comment: Please check above eddits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `database_repository` configuration doesn't contain any `argument` sections which are mapping for constructor parameters. In short, you don't provide requered parameters which are `DatabaseRepository` and `LoggerInterface` instances.

There's a `database_connection` service which represents the first one. More info about how to use DBAL in Symfony [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/dbal.html)

So to add it to you conf file you should modify it like this:

```
<service id="database_repository"
         class="Acme\DemoBundle\Doctrine\DatabaseRepository">
    <argument type="service" id="database_connection" />
</service>
```

You have also to add `LoggerInterface` instance but that's out of Symfony so you have to create a service for that in first place.

Please also refer to [Service Container documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html) in order to understand how services work in Symfony2